# Parsing JSON from text

Tags: python, regex, json

I'm wondering if this is a good method for parsing JSON out of a string:

```
json.loads(re.search("({(.+)})", text).group(1))
```

Can anyone give me an example where this wouldn't work?

Comment: Just found out `text="{}"` would fail, so maybe `({(.*)})` would be better?

Comment: I'm extremely confused. What are you trying to do? What would some sample input be and what would the sample output be?

Comment: I have a string that's `text="something{json data}else"` and I need to parse json out of it.

Comment: I have provided an example that doesn't work. Just stick a `}` in the text after the JSON or a `{` in the text before the JSON.

Comment: This fundamentally fails on JSON-encoded lists (aka javascript Arrays).

Comment: @roippi: That's another case where it'll fail. But I think there's an assumption that the top-level object will be an object, not a list. The question still isn't very clear.

Comment: Assuming that there's no extra text in the middle of the string as well, you could just search from the left for the first `{`, then from the right for the first `}`, then do `json.loads()` on the middle.

Comment: @JamesKelleher: That assumes both the leftmost and rightmost curly brace is part of the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find JSON in a string using Regex. Here's a simple way to fail it:

```
Some text before json {"something": {"inner": 5}, "another": {"yeah": 4}} some text which is after json {}.
```

Regex can't handle nesting without extensions (which aren't part of the Python standard library). You're using the wrong tool for this job.

It'll either grab too much when it's greedy (seeing a unmatched `{` or `}` in the text surrounding the JSON as part of the pattern) or it won't grab enough when it's non-greedy (by using a `?`)... it would only match from the first `{` to the first `}` if it's non-greedy.

Comment: Above code handles nesting just right. `json.loads(re.search('({(.*)})', 'Some text before json {"something": {"inner": 5}, "another": {"yeah": 4}} some text').group(1))` returns a nice JSON obj.

Comment: @user2115494: That's not my full example though. I have `{}` to the right of `some text` which you left off.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Thanks for the example!